# Updating GPS fields in unrelated fragments using a Handler()

Tags: android, android-fragments, gps, handler

I am trying to show current GPS data fields on fragment tabs that are not the fragment where the LocationListener is located (GpsData). Currently I have implemented a handler,

```
public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
  }
  private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    doUpdate();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
    }
  };
```

to update the fields every 5 secs by calling doUpdate (below),

```
private void doUpdate() {
        GpsData gps = new GpsData(getActivity());
        long lSatTime = gps.getSatelliteTime();
        Date date = new Date(lSatTime);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String szSatTime = sdf.format(date);
        textView.setText(szSatTime);
    }
```

While the handler method does work when only one fragment is accessing the GpsData resource, (e.g., long lSatTime = gps.getSatelliteTime()), when more than one fragment accesses this, I am getting NullPointerExceptions associated with GetLocation in GpsData. Any fragment by itself works fine when doUpdates() in the other fragments are commented out.

**Question:** Is there a way to resolve this conflict using Handler(), or would using a Listener be more appropriate for populating fields in multiple fragments. TIA,

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Square's Otto: http://square.github.io/otto/

It is an event bus for Android

This one too: http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/

Or if you want to stay "native", just build your "event bus" using LocalBroadcastManager?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html